# How can I send props to a third child component? or an array of components

Tags: vue.js, quasar

community. Me again and now with new problems.
I have this array of components. and their structure is the following.

```
|---Parent component 
  |
  |-- tabs component (to switch between components)
    |
    |--- view component (the page itself with data and stuff)
```

In parent component I want to add a button to the header, then call to a popup in the view component to add data and update the table. (I mean, send from the 1st component to the 3rd)

how can I do this?

My proposal of solution is to make an array of components

``

```
components: [
    {
      TabTitle: "General",
      TabNumber: "1",
      component: GeneralComponent, //previowsly imported from GeneralComponent.vue
    },
     {
      TabTitle: "Tables",
      TabNumber: "2",
      component: TablesComponent, //and add props here to receive them on the Tabs component
    },
  ],``
```

is this actually possible?

Comment: You can use state management such as Vuex, comes in very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

you can pass a prop to a component that passes the same prop to another component.

Vue can keep them straight.

Changing the value of the prop at the beginning of the chain will propagate through to all the components. this also means you if you want to change the value from one of the child components you will need to first `emit` https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html